# Buttons Width getting stretched while using autolayout in iPad screens?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I have a screen and i am using autolayout for the design purpose. The screen adjusts pretty well for all the screens in iPhone but in iPad the buttons get stretched a little making it weird to look . How to adjusts the autolayout for this? Below is my screenshot:

[image: iPhone screen]

[image: iPad Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to achive f.e you can set aspect ratio of first button (as I can see rest of them are equal width equal hight to it) to 1:1 and they wont streach but it will mess up your view. It depends how you want them to look on ipads without streaching them.

Comment: Click at it and then in adding new constrain menu you have option for adding aspect ratio then in constrain menu set it to 1:1 and you should be good to go. Here's [image](http://imgur.com/a/GPbip).

Comment: Doode.. It worked for me...is it possible to change the uiimageview and labels height accordingly in ipads?As you can see the labels height don't get  adjusted accordingly...

Comment: You can change these sizes by f.e. setting values to screen proportions like button width for whole view width and then multiplying it by e.g. 0.2 to achive same result for every device. Or implementing size classes here's good [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Comment: If I solved your problem would you mind accepting my answer? It will be clear that it is solved. ^^

Comment: Please support my question too :)

Comment: Here you go! :)

Comment: button stretches in i pad ok. Here is solution for that -Click i pad w-R h-R  go to vary for traits option right side down select both width and height , now start your design , dont change constraint what made previous, you can delete constraint, add as you want  sizes , after completing design press done verifying. Design completed now you can see as per i pad and i phone .